# Simulate smart card for digital signature

Tags: digital-signature, smartcard

I'm working on a project and I need digital signature, in order to confirm identity (read smart cards, a3).
But, the point is I have no card or card reader at the moment. Does anyone know a way I could kind of 'virtualize' a card, just like if a common one was plugged in, with a password I'd provide?
Thank you very much

(The solution must work on Windows 7)

Comment: Maybe http://frankmorgner.github.io/vsmartcard/virtualsmartcard/README.html ?

Comment: On which basis would you invent the identity the other party tries to verify?

Comment: The smart card will be used through the windows certificate keystore? Which programming language are you using? Web/local?

Comment: Java SE, desktop application. Local